# Make [undefined-behaviour] a synonym of [undefined-behavior]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

What it says on the tin: make [undefined-behaviour](/questions/tagged/undefined-behaviour) (4 questions) a synonym of [undefined-behavior](/questions/tagged/undefined-behavior) (200 questions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like we're a little bit backlogged on tag synonyms again.  That one was suggested back in August.  I approved it and merged the tags.

Comment: :o You should approve some of the others that are backlogged while you're in there. No need for separate meta topics, ya?

Comment: @animuson There are 22 pages of them at the moment.  I'm not going to know if most of them are good synonyms or not, so the community really should vote on them.

Comment: I'm confused how these pages work, why does the [suggested tab](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested) only show 10 things for me, but the rest all show up in the "all" tab?

Comment: @animuson Whoops, my bad.  I went through the moderator view and it defaulted to showing `all` synonyms.  There are only 6 pages of suggested synonyms.

Comment: @animuson If it's only showing 10 suggested synonyms for you, it must be filtering out tags that you're active in so you don't vote on everything.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense then. I tried going to another tag and seeing if it'd let me vote and it gave me a "you don't have a high enough score" message. How that's set up is a bit confusing though.